# Selenium throws Element not found exceptions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium with java and trying to automate some scenarios. I wrote a code to insert text in the field but the issue is that the element displays when I search for the element in the dom by xpath, id or name but when I run my script.

I get a "no such element found" error. Below is my code and below is the XML.

My code:

```
public void SearchByZipCode(String Zipcode) {
        WebElement addressfield = driver.findElement(By.name("addressline"));
        addressfield.sendKeys(Zipcode);
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.id("locator_submit"));
        search.click();
        WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='panel']//span[2]"));
        String text = result.getText();

        if (text.contains(Zipcode)) {
            System.out.println("Passed! Expected results for: " + Zipcode + "Actual result displayed for: " + text);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed! Expected results for: " + Zipcode + "Actual result displayed for: " + text);
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <input tabindex="3" style="padding:8px; width:90%; border:1px solid 
    #cdcdcd;" class="addressentry" type="text" size="40" name="addressline" 
    id="inputaddress" value="Enter street address, city, state or ZIP" 
    onclick="clear_inputbox(this);">
```

Comment: Validating your xPath would require viewing more of the DOM

Comment: Check your xpath. If you feel your xpath is proper then have an explicit wait after "search.click();" and wait for the element "(By.xpath("//div[@id='panel']//span[2]"))" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first use method, which will wait for this element to appear and become active. Then enter your value.
Also, better to use ID as selector, since it is available in your page.